# Why does request count of LB not work as a target tracking policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

This is from the documentation of Target Tracking in Auto-Scaling-Groups in AWS:
The following metrics do not work for target tracking:

The number of requests received by the load balancer fronting the Auto Scaling group (that is, the Elastic Load Balancing metric RequestCount). The number of requests received by the load balancer doesn't change based on the utilization of the Auto Scaling group.

[image]

My question is: Why does it not change? I have tried this and it works! Sending multiple requests to the load balancer and then it starts to scale. Why is it saying, that is does not scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initial Answer

The documentation states that the  number of requests received by the load balancer (RequestCount) does not work for target tracking scaling polices. The reason behind this is that target tracking scaling polices are desinged to work with metrics that represent the utilization or performance of the instances within the Auto Scaling grop, rather than the overal traffic received by the load balancer.

When you say taht you've tried it and it works, it's posible taht you might be using a diferent scaling policy tipe, such as Step Scaling or Simple Scaling, wich do allow you to use the RequestCount metric to triger scaling events.

In target tracking, the idea is to maintain a specific utilization level for a given metric, such as CPU utilization or another custom metric, by adding or removing instances as needed. Using RequestCount for target tracking would not be suitable becuse it doesn't provide a clear indication of the current utilization of the instances in the Auto Scaling grop.

So, RequestCount might work for other scaling policy tipes, but for target tracking scaling polices specifically, it's not the best choice, as it doesn't represent the utilization of the instances within the Auto Scaling grop.

### Update

I see from the screenshot that you are using "request count per instance".
RC per instance is not the same as overall RC or request count for the load balancer. So since this metric is "per instance" it makes sense that it works.